# Neo4j 2.3 on Talend connection issues

Tags: neo4j, talend

I am Failing to connect with the `tNeo4jConnection` with below error.

I am using *Neo4j 2.3*, but don't see this DBVersion listed in Talend, so I am using the *Neo4j 2.2.X* option in the dropdown.

Also, where do you set the user and password for the Neo4J database?

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 4019
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tNeo4jConnection_1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, C:\Users\shopp\Documents\Neo4j\Fluid4
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:335)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:95)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:176)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:67)
    at fluidactions.importneo4j_0_1.ImportNeo4j.tNeo4jConnection_1Process(ImportNeo4j.java:400)
    at fluidactions.importneo4j_0_1.ImportNeo4j.runJobInTOS(ImportNeo4j.java:2089)
    at fluidactions.importneo4j_0_1.ImportNeo4j.main(ImportNeo4j.java:1942)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager@1ee7a188' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
[statistics] disconnected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like the best work around for version 2.3 Talend Neo4j imports is placing the LoadCSV cypher into a tNeo4jRow.  This does of course involve an extra step of generating .csv files from the SQL server, but is still faster than using tNeo4jOutput component as per below.

When using tNeo4jOutput the import is incredibly slow, and then you need extra 2 cypher steps to actually label the nodes, and remove the NodeType field used for labelling the nodes.  See this chaps work around https://lucidwebdreams.wordpress.com/2014/07/24/import-data-into-neo4j-from-ms-sql-server-directly-using-talend/

Answer (score 0):

The *Neo4j 2.3* is not currently supported by Talend. However, just like you tried, the driver for *Neo4j 2.2* should work.

The user/passwork is only supported for a remote server. Please activate the option and set the server URL to `http://localhost:7474/db/data`.

Be sure to connect once on `http://localhost:7474/browser/` in order to change your password, or neo4j will block the connections.

Comment: thanks so much for replying and confirming that  is not supported.  However with 2.2. Driver 
(a) when i try to import in to an existing graph database i get the above error
(b) when i try to import into a non-existent database, i see a new database is created, but i cannot open this database as it is in an older version.

so i'm not having much luck with the 2.2 driver...any other suggestions ?

Comment: The `neo4j 2.2.X` Driver cannot to read an embedded `neo4j 2.3.X` Database. However you can start the neo4j server on your computer and access it as a remote server. This will solve the compatibility issues.

Comment: Ok that sounds great.  And how do i access it as a remote server? I have set the Talend tNeo4jOutput url = "http://localhost:7474/db/data". Set the user name and password as per my new Graph database.  The job runs successfully confirm rows have been sent,  but i have no idea where the nodes have been sent to, as they don;t appear in my running graph database.  Have i misunderstood how remote servers work.  Thanks again